# Magento - Change background image based on country selected

Tags: css, magento, localization, background

I have just been on next.co.uk and liked the way that they change the top right corner of their website when languages are selected. I.e. if you go on the german version you will see the website corner peeled over with a german flag behind it.

I was wondering if magento had anyway to do this as there is no change to the actual markup when the language is changed.

If it was possible to give the body a class depending on the language selected e.g. body class="german" then this would be ideal for styling pages to suit foreign layouts.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thankyou

Glynn 
Roco Clothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento does this already with the themes for French, German and English in 'demo store'.

What happen is that you have a base theme - the one you have worked on - and an over-ride theme, just the extras found in your **skins/frontend/default/country and app/design/frontend/default/country** folders. You do not need a complete clone of your base theme, just the updates.

You can also use normal linux soft links in your server, your `styles.css` could refer to a .`./images/bg.png` file that is different on each theme with the styles.css being the same.

Comment: Thankyou... so i have skin/frontend/defualt/mytheme in the same directory as skin/frontend/default/french and skin/frontend/default/german the default theme for everything is mytheme, even though they are in the same directory would it still overwrite it? I'll give it a go anyway and let you know....thankyou

Comment: just tested it by simply changing the html background colour to blue for french. Then changed the french store view skin theme to the french setting. It only used the one line of css and didn't override mytheme. i think maybe this technique would only work if I was using the default theme as my main theme. I might have to copy all my files over to that folder instead?

Comment: ..as Demo Store has it - not many extra files, just what is changed over 'default' (whatever your default theme is). As for the css, you can have theme specific updates, i.e. a main css file and then a view specific one that comes on top, maybe redefining some definitions, e.g. the body tag. That might be the easier way to do it. The catalog.xml has lots of addJs/css options you might want to look at too.

Comment: the theme default is in a box in admin, try putting your theme name in there at the top of the design tab in system/configuration.

Comment: Thankyou... I have solved the problem now using the 1column - 2column etc .phtml files and adding this code to the header:

Comment: <?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()==2): ?>
<html class="german" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<?php elseif (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()==3): ?>
<html class="french" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<?php else: ?>
<html class="english" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<?php endif ?>

Comment: If it works it works. Like the locale settings in the header.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing a store ID check and then modifying your HTML depending on the language of the store i.e.

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()==2): ?> // German Store
<body class="german">
<?php else: ?>
<body class="english">
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Hi, what file would i put this into I cant seem to find the template file containing the body tag!!

Comment: You will see the body tag is in the .phtml contained in the /template/page/ folder of your theme, the file you need to look at will depend on what type of theme you are using. You will see that the the class is already fetched from $this->getBodyClass() so if you are not 100% sure about what you need to do to change this you might what to try and implement your page graphic via another method, floating div etc.